# When using JsonLayout - attribute with index 5 contains incorrect layout, is it bug or feature or I have incorrect settings?

Tags: c#, nlog

When using JsonLayout - attribute with index 5 contains incorrect layout. (Check screenshot attribute[5]. Layout is JsonLayout instead of "${aspnet-request-url}")
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVVwB.png)

Config:

```yaml
"elastic": {
        "includeAllProperties": false,
        "index": "plarium.rocks.artem.8-${date:format=yyyy.MM}",
        "layout": {
          "Attributes": [
            {
              "layout": "${date:format=o}",
              "name": "time"
            },
            {
              "layout": "${level:upperCase=true}",
              "name": "level"
            },
            {
              "name": "logger",
              "layout": "${logger}"
            },
            {
              "layout": "${message:raw=true}",
              "name": "log_message"
            },
            {
              "layout": "${exception}",
              "name": "exception"
            },
            {
              "layout": "${aspnet-request-url}",
              "name": "empty-layout"
            },
            {
              "layout": "${aspnet-request-url}",
              "name": "request-url"
            },
            {
              "layout": "${aspnet-request-method}",
              "name": "request-method"
            },
            {
              "layout": "${aspnet-user-identity}",
              "name": "request-user"
            },
            {
              "layout": "${when:when='${level}'!='ERROR':inner=restricted:else=${aspnet-request-posted-body}}",
              "name": "request-body-payload"
            },
            {
              "layout": "${aspnet-request-ip}",
              "name": "request-remote-ip"
            },
            {
              "layout": "${aspnet-mvc-controller}",
              "name": "controller"
            },
            {
              "layout": "${aspnet-request-duration}",
              "name": "request-duration"
            },
            {
              "name": "properties",
              "encode": false,
              "layout": {
                "type": "JsonLayout",
                "includeallproperties": false
              }
            }
          ],
          "type": "JsonLayout"
        },
        "password": "",
        "requireAuth": true,
        "type": "ElasticSearch",
        "uri": "",
        "username": "",
        "enableJsonLayout": true
      },
```

References in the project: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b14bw.png)

Tried setting up the NLog target, but it's not set up correctly.

Comment: Maybe missing `"extensions": [ { "assembly": "NLog.Web.AspNetCore" } ]` to recognize `${aspnet}`-LayoutRenderers ? Have you tried adding `"throwConfigExceptions": true` or enabling [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging)-output ? See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json about using `LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings()`

Comment: Yeah, it exists in configuration, the only one difference that I use ` LogManager.Configuration = new NLogLoggingConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("NLog"));` for configuration. I tried to use `LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings()` but it is not help.

Comment: Without any details about what fails, and not providing any output from [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging). Then I can only suggest: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting